# Firefox: how to add textBox for a URL?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, browser

I am new to development of firefox tools.
Need to implement a text box similar to Google search box shown in the toolbar in my firefox bowser...and when i click enter...the URL

```
http://<URL>/
```

should be appended with the value that i have entered in text box and open the URL in new tab...
The problem is i am not able to find good resource to do the same.

I have tired to implement add-on but i guess that is not required.

Can you please help me on the same?

Please refer to the Pic below for more info...once the user enter the BUG ID then the new tab should open with the appended URL i.e the URL will be

```
http://<URL>/bugid
```

[image]

Comment: Can you upload togithub what you have so far, we can help you out.

Comment: Hey man I don't understand your situation, if you can explain more, show code, or images or something we can help you out more. Where you want to put your textbox is an important thing. And what do you mean by addon not required? If you want to make a change it has to be through addon. Unless are you just doing a personal change on your browser, like customize tools? Like move stuff in your nav bar?

Comment: Thanks @Noitidart, I have added pic for your reference..